# How to echo array elements in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to echo arry elemnts in view
followings are my code (controller)

```
$next_d_dts= \DB::table('tb_billing_cycle')->select('next_due_bill_date')->where('customer_id',$row->customer_id)->get(); 

return view('invoice.view')->with('next_d_dts',$next_d_dts);
```

I can print it using print function, eg:

```
print_r($next_d_dts);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [next_due_bill_date] => 2019-03-28 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [next_due_bill_date] => 2020-02-28 ) )
```

Comment: $next_d_dts["key_name"];

Comment: this is a collection not an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [iterate over the collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#loops) of objects:

```
@foreach ($next_d_dts as $object)
    {{ $object->name }}
@endforeach
```

If you just want to see its contents but not stop the script:

```
{{ var_dump($next_d_dts) }}
```

You've also asked how to iterate without Blade:

```
foreach ($next_d_dts as $object) {
    echo $object->name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@foreach($next_d_dts as $value)
{{$value['next_due_bill_date']}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

you should used foreach loop in laravel like this

```
@foreach ($next_d_dts as $value)
    <p>Some text here{{ $value->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

for more information read [Laravel Manual blade template](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade)

Also you can used

`dd($next_d_dts) //The dd function dumps the given variables and ends execution of the script`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it into array using `toArray()` and iterate over it

```
$next_d_dts= \DB::table('tb_billing_cycle')->select('next_due_bill_date')->where('customer_id',$row->customer_id)->get()->toArray();
```

In view

```
@foreach($next_d_dts as $value)
{{ $value['column_name'] }}
@endforeach
```

Or

`print_r($next_d_dts)`

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($array as $item)
    {{$item}}
@endforeach
```

Simple.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use [Blade Loops](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#loops)  syntax *invoice.view.blade.php*

```
@foreach($next_d_dts as $next )

 {{  $next }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: where is 'foreach()'

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: how to use without blade?